# Find user in AD LDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap

I've came across the problem of building the filter for LDAP.

**Few notes before the actual question:**

```
Фамилия = Family Name (will be presented as FamilyName)  
Имя = Name (will be presented as Name)  
Отчество = Patronymic (will be presented as Patronymic)
```

**I have a user with the following information in the AD:**

```
CN=Фамилия Имя Отчество
sn=FamilyName
givenname=Name
```

**I want to provide the following functionality:**

1. User can either enter the`Name FamilyName` in the field on the website, this will result in the array of 2 filters for `Name FamilyName` and `FamilyName Name`'
2. User can enter `Имя Фамилия`  and the search should switch from (&(sn=)(givenname=)) to (cn=)

Currently I have the following piece of code to accomplish the first option:

```
    /**
     * Generate search terms
     * @param string $query
     * @return LDAPSearcher
     */
    protected function generateSearchTerms(string $query) : self {
        $this->searchTerms = [];
        $explode = explode(' ', $query);
        $combinations = [];
        array_combinations($explode, $combinations);

        foreach($combinations as $index => $combination) {
            if (false !== strpos($combination, ' ')) {
                [$firstName, $lastName] = explode(' ', $combination);
                $this->searchTerms[] = [
                    'sn'        =>  $lastName,
                    'cn'        =>  $combination,
                    'givenname' =>  $firstName,
                    'filter'    =>  '(&(sn=' . $firstName . ')(givenname=' . $lastName . '))'
                ];
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

And it works just fine when user using the Latin representation of his/her First and Last names, but when I want to switch to using CN, I have no idea on how to do it. I've tried the following piece of code for the filter, however it shows that filter is incorrect:

`((&(sn=' . $firstName . ')(givenname=' . $lastName . '))|(cn=' . $combination . '*))`

**P.S.** it DOES NOT matter which variables I assign to SN or GivenName, since the combinations will match the correct user anyways, I'm running at most 3 searches for each user to ensure that the correct one is found (just to eliminate possibility of answers with assigning correct values to variables)

**P.P.S.** Combinations are generated using the following piece of code

```
if (! function_exists('array_combinations')) {

    function array_combinations(array $source, array &$target, ?string $tempString = null) {
        if ($tempString !== null) {
            $target[] = $tempString;
        }
        $size = \count($source);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            $copy = $source;
            $element = array_splice($copy, $i, 1);
            $tmp = null;
            if ($tempString !== null) {
                $tmp = $tempString . ' ' . $element[0];
            } else {
                $tmp = $element[0];
            }
            if (\count($copy) > 0) {
                array_combinations($copy, $target, $tmp);
            } else {
                $target[] = $tmp;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is indeed invalid.

In LDAP query syntax, a "this OR that" condition is written as `(|(this)(that))`. But you have put the `|` *between* your conditions. It needs to be *at the front*. It should look something like this:

```
(|(&(sn=' . $firstName . ')(givenname=' . $lastName . '))(cn=' . $combination . '*))
```